# How to display content checking only top level category?

Tags: wordpress

I need to display content only in Top Level Category using custom taxonomy

E.g:

```
if (is_top_level_category)
##Any content
else
##Nothing
```

Thank's ypu...

Comment: How do you fetch the categories? where is this displayed? On a sidebar I would handle this different then on a "category" page

Comment: In category page using taxonomy "product_cat" (Woocommerce)

Comment: That is an answer to 'what?' I'm asking 'how?'(code) and 'where?'(phpfile/template) Without these I cannot answer it.